# Moving the Camera Not the Background - Java

Tags: java, swing, paint

Currently in a **top down** game I am developing, I want the player to always be in the center of the screen.

To accomplish this, I am just moving the background down when I want the player to move up, and vice versa.

However, now that I am adding enemies and other objects into the game, I want to avoid the movement getting all wonky when the map moves behind them while they are trying to move also.

Is there any way I can move what the JFrame is viewing up, without changing the coordinates of the background image?

For a better explanation of what I am trying to accomplish, look at the drawing below. 
[image: Example]

Is what I am trying to accomplish too complicated? Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Why not use `JScrollPane` or `JViewPort` to move onto the map? (In this case you just have to manage the monsters, etc. directly onto the map...)

Comment: ("Is what I am trying to accomplish too complicated?"* Apply an [`AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(sx,sy)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#getTranslateInstance-double-double-) as & when needed.